# How do I deploy a Google Script project so that all my Google Sheets can access it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a simple VIN Decoder script that I built for my Vehicle DB Sheet.  I want to allow other sheets to use the functions defined in the script without copying the code to the script containers for each spreadsheet.  I guess I essentially want to have a private (to my account or domain) add-on.  I have tried reading about how to deploy an add-on to Google Workplace but all the tutorials are either old or just provide sample code that doesn't answer how to do it.  I am sure this is not a huge project to deploy this code as an add-on.  Anyone?

Here is the code I am trying to deploy...

```
const nhtsaGateway = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/';
const nhtsaVINDecode = '/vehicles/DecodeVin/';

function decodeVIN(theVIN,theVariable) {
  var response, jsonData, retValue, success;

  success = false;

  if (typeof(theVIN) === 'undefined') {
    theVIN = 'WD4PF0CD3KP053982';
    Logger.log('No VIN Submitted -- Assuming this is a test\nUsing Test VIN = [' + theVIN + ']');
  }

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(nhtsaGateway + nhtsaVINDecode + theVIN +'?format=JSON');
  jsonData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  Logger.log(jsonData.Message);

  if (typeof(theVariable) === 'undefined') {
    Logger.log(jsonData);
    return(jsonData);
  }

  jsonData.Results.every(function(element, index) {
    Logger.log('<<<' + index + '>>>');
    Logger.log(element.Value);
    Logger.log(element.ValueId);
    Logger.log(element.Variable);
    Logger.log(element.VariableId);

    if (element.Variable === theVariable) {
      Logger.log('Found theVariable = ' + element.Variable);
      retValue = element.Value;
      success = true;
      return (false);
    } else {
      return (true);
    }
  })

  if (success) {
    Logger.log(retValue);
    return (retValue);
  } else {
    Logger.log('We should not be here --> ' + theVariable + ' <-- is not defined in the NHTSA response.');
}

}

function vinYear(theVIN) {return (decodeVIN(theVIN,'Model Year'))}

function vinMake (theVIN) {return (decodeVIN(theVIN,'Make'))}

function vinSeries (theVIN) {return (decodeVIN(theVIN,'Series'))}

function vinModel (theVIN) {return (decodeVIN(theVIN,'Model'))}

function vinGVWR (theVin) {return (decodeVIN('1FTYR2CM2KKB15306', 'Gross Vehicle Weight Rating From'))}
```

So the usage in the target spreadsheet would be this formula in a cell
=vinModel("1FTYR2CM2KKB15306")

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to make an addon or an extension, just a library:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Comment: I tried to go into another sheet and open the script editor, add the VinDecode script ID.  All that was successful but I still cannot call any of the functions in the library from within a cell in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the name of the library in front of your function after adding the library, e.g.

```
Mylibrary.decodeVIN()
```